# Removing duplicates and sorting collected elements into value of a Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is `Person` class

```
public class Person {

    private String department;
    private long timestamp;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm trying to do collect them into `Map` using `groupingBy`

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map = 
        personList.stream()
              .collect(groupingBy(
                         Person::getDepartment,
                         mapping(Person::getTimestamp, toList())
                        )
                  );
```

This map has values of `List<Long>` and I wanted to remove duplicates and sort these lists. Therefore I used collectingAndThen, but it didn't work and gives error.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map = 
        personList.stream()
              .collect(groupingBy(
                         Person::getDepartment,
                         mapping(Person::getTimestamp, collectingAndThen(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Person::getTimestamp))),
                                ArrayList::new))));
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Just to make sure...do you want to remove duplicates from each lists or the whole map?

Comment: each list, thus only for List<Long> elements

Comment: Why not use `toSet()` instead of `toList()`? as your downstream collector? (and of course expect `Map<String, Set<Long>>`)

Comment: @ernest_k I would go a step further and not only create a Set, but also accomplish sorting by replacing toList() with `toCollection(TreeSet::new)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are collecting into `Map<String, List<Long>>` were list is of `Long` type, so you cannot sort the list using `Person::getTimestamp`. Since you are using `TreeSet` by default it will sort according to the natural ordering of its elements.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map1 = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDepartment,
                    Collectors.mapping(Person::getTimestamp,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                    Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new),
                                    ArrayList::new))));
```

Either converting `TreeSet` because it removes duplicates and by default sort according to the natural ordering of its elements.

```
Map<String, Set<Long>> map = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDepartment, Collectors.mapping(Person::getTimestamp,
                    Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)));
```

Comment: I get this error Error:(88, 35) java: method toCollection in class java.util.stream.Collectors cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<C>
  found: ()->new Tr[...]er())
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: java.lang.Object
    upper bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<? super T>,T,java.lang.Object

Comment: It works fine without Comparator.naturalOrder(). Thanx

Comment: I'm on Jdk-11 this is working for me without any issues @AdamJungen

Comment: Or use Comparator like this `Comparator.comparingLong(i->i)`, which is also working for me @AdamJungen

Comment: The `TreeMap` no arg constructor uses by default the natural ordering of its key, so you could do just : 

    `Map<String, List<Long>> map =
            personList.stream()
                      .collect(groupingBy(
                              Person::getDepartment,
                              mapping(Person::getTimestamp,
                                      collectingAndThen(toCollection(TreeSet::new), ArrayList::new))
                               )
                      );`

Comment: are you telling about `TreeSet` which has default natural sorting order? @davidxxx

Comment: @Deadpool. Yes  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap--  :)

Comment: Thank you @davidxxx i missed that one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like below

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
     List<Long> list = map.get(key);
     List<Long> listWithoutDuplicates = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
     map.put(key, listWithoutDuplicates)
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this with a stream and only one stream.